# Managing a log file in Grails

Tags: grails

Let me reword this entire thread.

I have a web application written using Grails and running on a VM, which is running Linux.

The web application needs to maintain a separate and distinct log file that contains very important information for the user of the application. I only want it to contain information that I am writing to it. Nothing else so I can't use Tomcat logging, etc. I need a separate log file because the user of the application is not savvy enough to read through a Tomcat log.

If I use a log file on the local C: drive it of course works when I run it in debug via IntelliJ but as soon as I war it up and drop it in Tomcat that no longer works and I get a ClassNotFoundException.

```
 String myCurrentDate = new Date().format( 'yyyyMMddhhmm' )
 def newFile = "C:\\Temp\\MyLogFile-Log-" + myCurrentDate + ".txt.old"
 def file = new File('C:\\Temp\\MyLogFile-Log.txt')
 file.renameTo( new File(newFile) )
 file.delete()
```

What's the best way to do this? Host the log file on the Linux machine? sftp doesn't seem to be the answer either. I need to be able to:

- Upon application execution rename the old log file to archive it and then delete the old log file
- write to the log file

If I do it on Linux how do I specify the file location?

Answer (score 1):

The recent versions of Grails are delivered with `logback` support. Usually you find a `logback.groovy` under `grails-app/conf`.

The example of a fully functional file:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy


appender( 'FILE', RollingFileAppender ){
  file = '/var/log/MyLogFile-Log.log'
  append = true
  encoder( PatternLayoutEncoder ){ pattern = '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %level %logger{36} - %msg%n' }
  rollingPolicy( TimeBasedRollingPolicy ){
    fileNamePattern = '/var/log/MyLogFile-Log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'
    maxHistory = 30
  }
}

logger 'com.your.important.package', INFO

root INFO, 'FILE'
```

Here a `RollingFileAppender` is used, creating backup-files each day.

Comment: I'm currently stuck using grails 2.2.5, I take it this isn't available in this version? appender is coming up unresolvable.

Comment: see http://docs.grails.org/2.2.5/guide/single.html#logging then. The structure of the config's section looks very similar to logback. The class names must be changed of course